# target first sibling of every group of elements with similar class

Tags: javascript, jquery, siblings, jquery-traversing

I need to target every first `div.bar`. I went through many ways but with no success with jQuery, although it seemed easy at first.

I need this in order to wrap all the div.bar after, but this I can do with `.wrapAll()` afterwards.

```html
<div id="aaa">
  <div class="bar" />
  <div class="bar" />
  <div class="bar" />
</div>
<span id="bbb">
          <div class="bar" />
          <div class="bar" />
          <div class="bar" />
        </span>
<div id="ccc">
  <div class="bar" />
  <div class="bar" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could  use `:first-child`:

```
$('.bar:first-child').wrap('<div class="test"/>');
```

Comment: Perfect, I forgot this selector! Thanks a lot sir